Is it true that the ultrapower of a transitive model of ZFC is set-like?
I thought a proof of this sentence, but I don't know if this sentence is true, and therefore if this proof is valid.
Let $(M,\in)$ be a transitive model of ZFC, $I$ a set of indices and $U$ an ultrafilter on $I$. Let $M^{I}/U$ the ultrapower of $M$ and let $\in^{U}$ the membership relation on $M^{I}/U$ (we can think that the elements of $M^{I}/U$ are sets using Scott's trick).
I want to prove that $\in^{U}$ is a set-like relation. Let $(x_i)\in M^{I}/U$. It is a set, so it has a Von Neumann rank $\rho((x_i))$, say $\alpha$. I want to show that every $(y_i)\in M^{I}/U$ such that $(y_i)\in^{U}(x_i)$ has rank $\leq \alpha$. So $\{(y_i)\in M^{I}/U \,\mid\, (y_i)\in^{U}(x_i)\}$ has to be a set.
By Łoś theorem we know that $(y_i)\in^{U}(x_i)\iff \{i\in I \,\mid\, M\models y_i\in x_i\}\in U$. In particular this implies that $\{i\in I \,\mid\, M\models \rho(y_i)<\rho(x_i)\}\in U$. Because $M$ is transitive, then $M\models \rho(y_i)<\rho(x_i)\iff \rho(y_i)<\rho(x_i)$. So for all $(y_i)\in^{U} (x_i)$ it is true that $\{i\in I \,\mid\, \rho(y_i)<\rho(x_i)\}\in U$. But by Scott's trick, $(y_i)$ has to be the rank-minimal element of its equivalence class, so it has to be $\rho(y_i)\leq\rho(x_i)$ for all $i\in I$. And it implies that $\rho((y_i))\leq \rho((x_i))=\alpha$.
Is it a valid proof? If not, where is the mistake? And if the sentence is false, what's a counterexample?

Rank minimality does not imply that $\rho(y_i) \leq \rho(x_i)$ for all $i \in I$, but you don’t really need this.

But if there are $i\in I$ such that $\rho(y_i)>\rho(x_i)$, I can substitute $(y_i)$ with $(z_i)$ defined as $z_i=y_i$ when $\rho(y_i)\leq \rho(x_i)$ and $z_i=0$ otherwise.  Because ${i\in I \mid \rho(y_i)\leq\rho(x_i)}\in U$, then $(y_i)$ and $(z_i)$ are in the same equivalence class and $\rho((z_i))\leq \rho((y_i))$.

Yes so $(y_i)$ has the same rank as $(z_i)$ but this doesn’t mean that $\rho(y_i) \leq \rho(z_i)$ for all $i$.

But I can use $(z_i)$ instead of $(y_i)$ as representative of the equivalence class of $[(y_i)]$, and $\rho(z_i)\leq \rho(x_i)$ for all $i\in I$.

Ok, I noticed now that I can't substitute a representative of an equivalence class with another. I can however conclude because $(y_i)$ has the same rank of $(z_i)$ and $\rho(z_i)\leq \rho(x_i)$ for all $i$, so $\rho((z_i))\leq \rho((x_i))$. Is it right?

Yes, that’s right!
